# Syntax issue in Clojure Koan - anonymous function has extra ()

Tags: clojure

06_function.clj contains this question, I can't figure out why there is an extra pair of () in position 1 and 2, since position 3 already has brackets wrapped up.

```
"One function can beget another"
  (= 9 (
        (   <---- 1
         (fn [] (fn [a b] (+ a b)))  <----3
         )  <-----2
        4 5))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(fn [a b] (+ a b))
```

is a function that takes 2 arguments and returns their sum, let's substitute if with name `fun1`

```
(fn [] fun1)
```

is a function that takes nothing and returns function object `fun1`. Let's call this new function `fun2`

```
( 
  fun2
)
```

here we call `fun2`, which, as we previously discussed, returns function `fun1`

```
(
  fun1
4 5)
```

here we call `fun1` (returned from `(fun2)`) with 2 arguments - `4` and `5`. This gives us `9`

```
(= 9
  9)
```

and finally we check equality of 2 numbers. They are actually equal.

The main thing you should understand here is that functions in Clojure are also first-class citizens. You may produce them (like `fun1`), pass them to other functions and return from them (like we returned `fun1` from `fun2`). So each layer of `(` and `)` is just another call to a function (possibly returned from some other function).

Answer (score 2):

It's there to evaluate the function created by outer `fn`.

So, in turn:

```
(fn [a b] (+ a b)
```

creates the inner function that sums it's arguments

```
(fn [] (fn [a b] (+ a b))
```

creates the outer function with taking zero arguments and returning a function that sums it's arguments.

```
(   
     (fn [] (fn [a b] (+ a b)))  
)
```

forces evaluation of the outer function (and returns it's result - a function that sums two values).

Remember that *when you see parentheses in lisps the first thing that should pop in your mind is that it's an application of the function/form/macro to it's arguments.*